# Hide Empty Legend for PIE Chart in Crystal Report

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, legend, suppress

I have a Pie chart with Group expert in my web application. Group expert is based on address and I have two data table in my crystal report Data sources.
One is for Pie Chart input and another one is just for warning message if no pie chart is being display.

All are working fine except for one case. If no record found for pie chart then it displays the empty legend as follows:

[image]

I have tried using formula by suppress but its not working.

```
 if Count({AppComp.Type}) = 0 Then False else True
```

Comment: `No record found` means `0` or `null`?

Comment: I am not clear on it. I just know only, there will be no records

Comment: you need to be clear on that... otherwise how can the condition be formed? just test the report removing all records from database and check the result

Comment: I have tested now. The first dataTable dont have any records but second table have values but which is not for Pie chart

Comment: ok what is the value in `pie chart` if there are no records in table?

Comment: It display 0% legend value like above image

Comment: Are you able to see any supress condition for legend?